# Why does the page in WordPress is showing 404 errror?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I could create pages in WordPress, but whenever I take that corresponding URL

```
eg:BaseUrl/page-slug/
```

the page is not loading, also showing a 404 error. I set the permalink

```
 hostname/%postname%/
```

I have used the same theme in my local it was working fine but in the server, it behaves like this. Please anyone can help me?

Comment: Did you make sure you have `mod_rewrite` enabled?

Comment: Please, the mod_rewrite module is enabled. If yes then go to reset permalinks.
Step 1 : Goto wp-admin->setting->permalinks 
Steps 2 : After save changes

Answer (score 0):

Would you please save permalin?

**Step 1 :** Goto `wp-admin->setting->permalinks` 
**Steps 2 :** After save changes

[image: Permalink]

Comment: I have already changed my permalink settings after I change the server. Even though showing a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens if something goes wrong with rewrite rules or your .htaccess file gets deleted. You should fix your permalink settings.

Go to Settings> Permalinks and click the Save Changes button. That should solve your problem!